# How can I get the number of days from specific date to CURRENT_DATE()

Tags: sql, hive, teradata

I have some query I'm running in Teradata SQL Assistant on Hive - I want to choose only persons older then 18 y.o.
I have in the Person_table column date_of_birth in format 24/02/2000

Here is my query:

> select  name as name from Person_table where (CURRENT_DATE() -
> date_of_birth) / 365 > 18

What I'm doing wrong? I didn't found some working example of this sort.

Update: my fault - it was HIVE, had to admit it in the question

Comment: Are you getting an error or just not the expected results?

Answer (score 0):

Try using an `INTERVAL` instead, something like:

```sql
select name as name 
from Person_table 
where CURRENT_DATE - date_of_birth INTERVAL YEAR(4) >= 18
```

I don't have a `TD` system to test, but that's the general approach.  Give it a try and let me know.

Comment: Not worked. Parse Exception - cannot recognize input near 'INTERVAL ' '"YEAR"'

Comment: Correct syntax is `where CURRENT_DATE - date_of_birth INTERVAL YEAR(4) >= 18`, but this will not work as expected, because it's not based on month/day but on year only.

Answer (score 0):

Change your logic to:

```
where date_of_birth <= add_months(CURRENT_DATE, -18*12)
```

This assumes that `date_of_birth` is actually a date, if it's a string you must cast it first:

```
where to_date(date_of_birth, 'dd/mm/yyyy') <= add_months(CURRENT_DATE, -18*12)
```

Answer (score 0):

select name as name
from Person_table
where DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE(), date_of_birth ) /365.25 >18

It's worked.

Comment: DATEDIFF is not a valid Teradata SQL function. Might be a UDF, if it's a SQL UDF it's a wrapper for your initial calculation. Btw, my logic is more efficient as there's no calculation involved :-)

Comment: @dnoeth, OP updated the question. It's Hive, not Teradata.

Comment: I'am in Teradata SQL Assistant on Hive